# how to check multiple buttons click and save the value on plist?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have 6 `UIButtons`.

- Easy
- hard
- Plus
- Minus
- Divide
- Multiply

can click on `"Easy mode"` or `"Hard mode"` one button at a time?

Can I click on any button and more than one button same time(Plus,Minus,Multiply,Divide)?

now I want on click which buttons one or more at a time will get those buttons value only.

means

- easy- plus
- easy- plus,minus
- easy- plus, minus, divide
- easy- multiply,divide,minus
- easy- plus, minus, divide
- easy- minus, multiply, plus

same as "Hard" case.

These are the conditions. But I want to count the common Scores. How can I store these values and save on `NSMutableArray`?

Comment: wt u want ..please explain clearly :(

Comment: take one method for all button..and give tag to all of your button :)

Comment: please write in understandable english, this is very difficult to understand. I dont know which part of Asia you belong...but language problem puts you down.

Comment: set `button.exclusiveTouch = NO`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*If I understood what you want then here is some logic. You can add/remove to make upto your requirement.

**Directly typed here, errors/typos probable. Please conside.*

In your interface file:

```
@property BOOL yourChoice;//0-easy, 1-hard
@property BOOL plus;
@property BOOL minus;
@property BOOL divide;
@property BOOL multipy;
@property (strong) NSInteger score;
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *scores;
```

In your implementation file:

```
-(IBAction)easy:(id)sender{
    yourChoice=0;
}

-(IBAction)hard:(id)sender{
    yourChoice=1;
}
```

In choices action method, instead of tag i am checking it with title to make it readable.

```
//NSString *title=[(UIButton *)sender currentTitle]; //to get name in ios
-(IBAction)choices:(id)sender{// i have used osx style
     NSString *title=[(UIButton *)sender currentTitle];
     if([title isEqualToString:@"Plus"]) plus=1;
     else if([title isEqualToString:@"Minus"]) minus=1;
     else if([title isEqualToString:@"Divide"]) divide=1;
     else if([title isEqualToString:@"Multiply"]) multiply=1;
     self.score=plus+minus+divide+miltiply;
}

-(IBAction)showScore:(id)sender{
   NSString *choice=yourChoice?@"Hard":@"Easy";
   NSLog(@"Score for %@ is %d.", choice, self.score);

   self.scores[self.scores.count]=@(self.score);
   //reset every value
   youChoice=plus=minus=divide=multiply=score=0;

}
```